# emacs tramp mode does not respect .clang-format in the remote directory

Tags: emacs, clang-format, tramp

I have a git repo with a `.clang-format` and a `simple.c` source code. In local mode, namely editing off local disk, it respects the style file. However if I edit using tramp mode the same repo, then `clang-format` will format the source code using some default style file (I don't know where it's picked up), and will NOT honor the style file existing in the same remote directory.

Q1: How do I fix this?

Q2: (Maybe it's easier) Where does clang-format in tramp-mode pick up the style file by default?

Comment: I suppose you're using `clang-format.el` from MELPA. I don't know anything about, but scanning this file shortly it looks like it doesn't support remote work. For example, it uses `call-process-region`, which isn't aware of remote hosts.

Comment: I've tried `tramp-call-process-region` and `tramp-sh-handle-call-process-region`; both didn't work.  As I understand it, `tramp-mode` copies the remote file to a local directory under `/var`; I've also tried placing `.clang-format` under `/var` to no avail.

Comment: No, that's not the way. `call-process-region` would need a counterpart `process-file-region`, which doesn't exist. So one must write this function first.

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus I'm not familiar with how tramp-mode works.  Could you describe what the supposed functionality of `process-file-region` would be?

Answer (score 4):

If you have root permissions on the local host, creating a directory `/ssh:host:` and copying `.clang-format` from the remote host to `/ssh:host:/path/to/.clang-format` will solve the issue.

This is because `clang-format` package for Emacs passes `buffer-file-name` to the local `clang-format` executable, and for remote files `buffer-file-name` is a [Tramp file name](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/File-name-syntax.html), which is handled specially by Emacs, but is unknown to `clang-format`. Nothing prevents you from creating a file with that exact name on the local host, after which `clang-format` will be able to find and read the corresponding `.clang-format` config file.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I was able to work around this issue:

1. I copied the `.clang-format` file from the remote location into my home directory.
2. I wrote the following wrapper function to replace the `--assume-filename` argument with a path referring to a file with the same name in the home directory:

```
  (defun my-clang-format-region ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((start (if (use-region-p) (region-beginning) (point)))
          (end (if (use-region-p) (region-end) (point)))
          (assumed-filename (if (file-remote-p buffer-file-name)
                                (concat (getenv "HOME") "/" (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name))
                               buffer-file-name)))
      (clang-format-region start end clang-format-style assumed-filename)))
  (global-set-key '[(control meta tab)] 'my-clang-format-region)
```

It seems that `--assume-filename` can specify a path to a file that doesn't exist. All `clang-format` seems to care about is the file's extension and directory path; it uses the directory path as a location to look for the `.clang-format` file. If it doesn't find the file there, it looks in every ancestor directory starting from that location.

This worked for me with versions 9.0 and 10.0 of the `clang-format` executable, and `clang-format.el` version 20190824.2216 from melpa.